# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c++ Can't find error

Tags: c++

I dont seem to be able to find the source of the error. The code defines a struct called boolfunc. I define a function to add two boolfunc(s). I get the error: segmentation fault (core dumped). I know what it means but where is the source of the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class boolfunc {
public:
  int num_var;
  int num_terms;
  vector<vector<int> > func;
  boolfunc addfunc(boolfunc f1, boolfunc f2);
};

boolfunc addfunc(boolfunc f1, boolfunc f2)
  {
    boolfunc f3;
    f3.func.resize(0);
    f3.num_terms = f1.num_terms + f2.num_terms;
    int var_dif = f1.num_var - f2.num_var;
    if(var_dif >= 0)
        {
        f3.num_var=f1.num_var;
        f3.func.resize(f1.num_var);
        f2.num_var=f1.num_var;
            f2.func.resize(f1.num_var);
        for(int i=0; i<f2.num_terms; ++i)
            {
            for(int j=0; j<var_dif; ++j)
                {
                f2.func[i].push_back(-1);
                }
            }
        }
    else
        {
        f3.num_var=f2.num_var;
        f3.func.resize(f2.num_var);
        f1.num_var=f2.num_var;
        f1.func.resize(f2.num_var);
        for(int i=0; i<f1.num_terms; ++i)
            {
            for(int j=0; j<(-1)*(var_dif); ++j)
                {
                f1.func[i].push_back(-1);
                }
            }
        }
    for(int i=0; i<f1.num_terms; ++i)
        {
        f3.func[i]=f1.func[i];
        }   
    for(int j=0; j<f2.num_terms;++j)
        {
        f3.func[j+f1.num_terms]=f2.func[j];
        }
    return f3;
    }

int main()
{
boolfunc ef1, ef2, ef3;
ef1.func.resize(0);
ef2.func.resize(0);
ef3.func.resize(0);
cout<< "Input the number of variables of function 1" <<endl;
cin>> ef1.num_var;
cout<< "Input the number of variables of function 2" <<endl;
cin>> ef2.num_var;
cout<< "Input the number of terms of function 1" <<endl;
cin>> ef1.num_terms;
cout<< "Input the number of terms of function 2" <<endl;
cin>> ef2.num_terms;
ef1.func.resize(ef1.num_terms);
  for(int i=0; i<ef1.num_terms; ++i)
    {
    ef1.func[i].resize(ef1.num_var);
    for(int j=0; j<ef1.num_var; ++j)
        {
    cout<<"For function 1, Input the term "<<i+1<<"'s variable "<<j+1<<"'s     value:";
        cin>>ef1.func[i][j];
        }
    }
ef2.func.resize(ef2.num_terms);
  for(int i=0; i<ef2.num_terms; ++i)
    {
    ef2.func[i].resize(ef2.num_var);
    for(int j=0; j<ef2.num_var; ++j)
        {
    cout<<"For function 2, Input the term "<<i+1<<"'s variable "<<j+1<<"'s     value:";
        cin>>ef2.func[i][j];
        }
    }
ef3 = addfunc(ef1, ef2);
for(int i=0; i<ef3.num_terms; ++i)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<ef3.num_var; ++j)
        {
        cout<<ef3.func[i][j]<<' ';
        if(j==ef3.num_var -1) cout<<endl;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by [looking at the coredump in gdb (or your debugger of choice/platform)](http://mytechrants.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/debugging-a-segmentation-fault-using-gdb/). Note there might be better "how to" on the web, but this was one of the first I found.

Comment: So, at which line is the seg fault generated ?  If you haven't narrowed it down to a line, in which block ?

Comment: The easiest bug for fixing is the one, which can be reproduced each time you run your program and which causes a crash. This way, you know for sure where's the problem and you may easily catch it using a debugger. Try it.

Comment: 1) Indent your source properly. 2) Never, ever, ever use unchecked input operations. I won't even look any further. 3) Replace `[i]` by `.at(i)` to see whether your index computations are wrong.

Comment: Summary - please do some debugging first, then copy your complex, array-indexing, array-resizing, source to SO with your debug results, (assuming you haven't found the complete solution by then). Your code has some cout's - did any of them output anything?  What do you expect from us? Have every skilled, experienced developer on SO to rebuild your code and have all of them debug it by all going over the same steps that you have already taken?  Why don't you tell us what output you get? Why can't you do some debugging?

Comment: Am sorry for not debugging myself... It was because I did not know how to debug...

Comment: 'I did not know how to debug' - that means that you cannot develop software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to approach this:

### Build and run

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O0 -ggdb main.cpp
gdb --args ./a.out
```

With the example vector (0,0,1,0) your program fails at line 49:

```
f3.func[i]=f1.func[i];
```

With the error:

```
Input the number of variables of function 1
0
Input the number of variables of function 2
0
Input the number of terms of function 1
1
Input the number of terms of function 2
0

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402930 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::capacity (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:652
652              - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000402930 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::capacity (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:652
#1  0x0000000000401bf3 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator= (this=0x0, __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:164
#2  0x0000000000400fc3 in addfunc (f1=..., f2=...) at main.cpp:49
#3  0x0000000000401558 in main () at main.cpp:92
```

### Analyse

If you look at the boundary where your program ends and the standard library starts, we immediately see the bug:

```
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator= (this=0x0, __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:164
```

As you can see `NULL` is passed as `this` argument to `std::vector<..>::operator=` which means your `f3.func` vector has the wrong size.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest one: use valgrind.

Like this: http://codepad.org/uSfdSK5d

Better question form may have had provided more detailed answer.