# Segmentation fault when trying to do a descrete Fourier Transform with complex numbers

Tags: c++

I tried to write a DFT function with C++. This function will take a vector of complex numbers, apply DFT then return another vector of complex numbers. Then I tried to make that read files from my computer, applied that function, then wrote the result to other files. When I run it, I got a segmentation fault. Follow the first comment in this site ([Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c++ Can't find error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139297/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-c-cant-find-error)), I ran gdb to the code, then it returned this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555557088 in std::complex<double>::__rep (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/10/complex:1363
1363          _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR _ComplexT __rep() const { return _M_value; }
```

I then dig deeper and found that g++, the complier I used, got that problem in version 4.9. I checked mine, and got this:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const float pi = 3.14159265358979;

vector<complex<double>> dft(vector<complex<double>> x){
    int N = x.size();
    vector<complex<double>> X;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){
        double re = 0;
        double im = 0;        
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++){
            double phi = (2 * pi * k * n) / N;
            re += x[n].real() * cos(phi);
            im -= x[n].imag() * sin(phi);
        }
        complex<double> result (re, im);
        X.push_back(result);
    }
    return X;
}

int main(){
    string temp;
    vector<complex<double>> x, y;
    vector<complex<double>> result_x, result_y;
    ifstream x_data, y_data;
    x_data.open("x.txt", ios::in);
    y_data.open("y.txt", ios::in);
    ofstream res_x, res_y;
    res_x.open("result_x.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    res_y.open("result_y.txt", ios::out | ios::app); 
    while(x_data >> temp){
        float temp_0 = stof(temp);
        complex<double> adder (temp_0, 0);
        x.push_back(adder); 
    }
    while (y_data >> temp){
        float temp_0 = stof(temp);
        complex<double> adder (temp_0, 0);
        y.push_back(adder);
    }
    result_x = dft(x);
    result_y = dft(y);
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k <= result_x.size(); k++){
        int freq = k;
        float amp_x = abs(result_x[k]);
        float phase_x = arg(result_x[k]);
        float amp_y = abs(result_y[k]);
        float phase_y = arg(result_y[k]);

        res_x << "[" << freq << ", " << amp_x << ", " << phase_x << "]" << endl;
        res_y << "[" << freq << ", " << amp_y << ", " << phase_y << "]" << endl;

    }
    x_data.close();
    y_data.close();
    res_x.close();
    res_y.close();
    cout << "DONE!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the test data?  How do we know the data you're using is valid?  Get rid of this:: `x_data.open("x.txt", ios::in);` and lines that look like this and hard-code test data that causes the issue in the program.  Right now, this is not a [mcve].

Comment: `for (unsigned int k = 0; k <= result_x.size(); k++)` -- Using `<=` as a loop termination condition leads to off-by-one errors.  The issue has nothing to do with the compiler.  Change this line: `float amp_x = abs(result_x[k]);` to `float amp_x = abs(result_x.at(k));`, and see if a `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown.

Comment: Also, *every* standard ANSI C++ compiler, regardless of brand or version, g++, clang, Visual Studio, etc. will throw an `out_of_range` exception if the issue is what is suspected.  This is where using `at()` as a debugging tool becomes essential and a time-saver.  Using `[ ]` to access elements does not guarantee a crash or an exception being thrown  if you go out of bounds of the vector -- using `at()` does have this guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you have used `k <= result_x.size()` in your for loop instead of `k < result_x.size()`. So at the last iteration(when `k = result_x.size()`) you get **undefined behavior** for `result_x[k];`. You can **solve** this by modifying the for loop to look like :

```
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < result_x.size(); k++){//note i've used < instead of <=
//...other code here
}
```

Comment: Further review: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eeac3b3099681bc9